# PHP: Handling multiple submit buttons the same way, but with different arguments

Tags: php, mysql, forms, web

I am trying to make a menu to assign contact lenses to patients. Every lens-option has a div with info about the lens, a range-input for strength and a submit button.

I would like to assign the ID of the lens to the patient in MySQL when the submit button of the specific lens is pressed. How can I handle this without having to copy-paste the `if(isset($_POST[submitbutton#])` for every lens?

I am currently considering a switch-statement.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Show us your current code so we can work around that.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It would be helpful if you could provide code samples, it might increase your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: simply add two submit button with different value and name.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].